# HTML/CSS giving li a margin and dont effect other childs

Tags: html, css

He guys!

Got the next problem:

Got a menu with a UL and LI elements, now when I hover above a  inside my LI I want to increase the font, that all works but the elements right from the changing element all move a bit to the right to create space, but there is space enough for them to stand still.

here is my code:

```
.unlistedList {
    position:relative;
    list-style:none;
    min-width:100%;
}

.listedLink {
    position:relative;
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 5em;
    display: inline-table;
    float:left;
}

.linkA {
    font-size:12px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #146432;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    transition: all  0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -o-transition:all 0.5s;
}

.linkA:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#20a150;
}
```

with :

```
<ul class="unlistedList">
  <li class="listedLink"><a href="#" class="linkA">Home</a></li>
  <li class="listedLink"><a href="#" class="linkA">About Us</a></li>
  <li class="listedLink"><a href="#" class="linkA">Portfolio</a></li>
  <li class="listedLink"><a href="#" class="linkA">Services</a></li>
  <li class="listedLink"><a href="#" class="linkA">Blog</a></li>
  <li class="listedLink"><a href="#" class="linkA">Contact Us</a></li>
```

I know the classes at ul and il are not needed but I just tested all things and I cant get it to work.

Comment: have you tried text-aligning center?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give the `li` an explicit width that will be greater than or equal to the width of the `a` when it's expanded. Now this would mean that your `li` won't be able to grow in width according to the length of its text. If that's what you need as well, I have no solution for that and I open it up to the great people of Stack.

http://jsfiddle.net/TreeTree/M5XPZ/

```
.listedLink {
    position:relative;
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
    width:100px;
    display: inline-table;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: That I didnt thought about that haha! Thank you very much!